# I'm looking for a way to create new "primitive" types with additional constraints which are visible at coding time to users of the type

Tags: c#, types, dto

Suppose I have an entity in my universe of discourse called a `Widget`. 
Suppose the `Widget` has an attribute called a `WidgetCode`. This attribute is defined (by the system of record) to be an alphanumeric value (ie, it's a string) of length exactly 8.

I might implement that in code as follows:

```cs
class Widget 
{ 
    private string _WidgetCode;
    public string WidgetCode 
    { 
        get => _WidgetCode;
        set 
        { 
            if (value.Length != 8) { throw new Exception("length must be 8"); }
            _WidgetCode = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is OK, but not ideal. The test in the setter will prevent the property from accepting an invalid value at runtime. But if some other developer wants to make use of my class, then the only way they can find out that the constraint exists is by looking at the implementation of the setter. Which would, of course, violate some pretty fundamental computer science 101 concepts.

In contrast we can look into the world of relational databases. In that world there is a fundamental type. "character", but I can create what is essentially a completely different type when I actually make use of it by specifying the length as part of the type. In the case of a `WidgetCode`, that would be a char(8). I can add other restrictions as well, in the form of check constraints.

When I do this, I have effectively created a new, more "refined" primitive type, which represents a `WidgetCode`, and does not represent any arbitrary string value of any arbitrary length.

More importantly, any SQL developer who needs to interact with my schema can see the constraints on my new type. They don't have to go and read separate documentation stored outside the schema. They don't have to live in ignorance of the constraint and hope that they never run afoul of some hidden constraint that they can't see while writing code. The constraint is *declared* in the schema, and the same thing which implements the constraint *also* documents it. It is impossible for the "documentation" to get out of synch with the implementation.

This idea doesn't have to be limited to strings. We might want to store a property called `Percentage`, and declare its domain as a real number between 0 and 1 with scale 3, such that it should not be possible to write the value 1.5 to this property. Once again in a relational schema, that could be a `Percentage decimal(4,3) not null check (Percentage between 0 and 1)`.

Is there any mechanism in C# whereby that same kind of more refined type can be created, and where developers using that type can see the constraint at coding-time without having to go and read some external documentation, hoping that the documentation is up to date?

DataAnnotations get some of the way there, but they are clearly designed to inform *users* (specifically of GUIs) about a problem with an entered value at runtime. I am looking for a similar kind of tagging which provides the same information to *developers* making use of the type at coding time.

Comment: What about Data Annotations? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6

Comment: Your example is very confusing - can you show and example of useful compile time constraint on values of such type (I don't see ever need to set some external entity property at compile time to start with...). Note that "constant" values of such type ( like `WidgetCode.Missing`) are trivial to implement but it does not sound like you are looking for that...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It doesn't have to be a constraint which can be checked by the compiler, just one which is visible to the coder.

For example, in SQL this is trivial. I can declare column as char(8), and this definition is visible to someone who tries to write to that column. If I write a stored procedures which tries to do something like this:
`declare @widgetCode varchar(8) = "abcdefghijklmnopq"`
The "compilation" of the stored procedure won't catch it, but the developer can clearly see that there is a problem without actually executing that line of code.

Comment: @Matthew Yeah, I looked into Data Annotations, but they seem more focused on interaction with a user. For example, the ability to set an error message which can be displayed to the user submitting data if the constraint is violated. In my case, however, there is no "user" who can receive such a message. The goal here is to make it easier for developers who make use of the class in their own code. The goal is not to provide nicer error information in the runtime environment.

Comment: It's still very unclear and overall post feels too broad for SO... I don't get why you insist that your type must be compatible with string for example - none of .NET basic types are assignable from string and no one complains (much)... Clearly you have some reasons why your type must support assigning from strings - but you don't explain why... (And SQL comparison does not help much - there are plenty of other constraint that can be set on column of `varchar(8)` that do not show up in that definition)

Comment: The "primitive types" in .NET (like `bool` or `int`) are just *value types*; i.e., a type declared as a `struct`. You can implement your own "primitive type" and implement whatever rules you want within your type

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov There are plenty of declarative constraints you can put on columns in SQL, yes. And those constraints are all visible to people interacting with the schema. That's precisely what I'm getting at.

It is *not* the case that, in SQL, if an integer column has a constraint on it - say `someInt int check (someInt between 0 and 10)`, that the only way I can find this out is by trying to assign numbers to it until the constraint is violated. 

I was wondering whether there was any mechanism to do something similar in c#. Data Annotations are close, but not quite there.

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, I said that in the original question. I created a struct to hold the WidgetCode, and pointed out that "Now the length constraint on the WidgetCode type can be implemented by the type itself".

But how does a consumer of my `Widget` class *know* that the `WidgetCode` property has a maximum length associated with it? I could put it in documentation somewhere, sure. In my data dictionary, for example. Which sits *outside* the code, and is not necessarily reflective of the code.

Comment: It might help if you knew the name of what you are describing. You are describing a type system feature called *dependent types* -- that is, *types that depend on a value that can be manipulated according to the algebraic rules of that value*. Types like "even integer" or "fraction between 0 and 1" and so on are simple examples of dependent types.  C# does not support dependent types.

Comment: The obvious power of dependent types is the scenarios you mention; you want to be able to detect what would be runtime errors at compile time. But the real power comes in the algebraic manipulations. Imagine a type `Stack<T, nonnegativeint n>` where T is the type of the elements and n is the size of the stack. We can then write the signatures `Stack<T, n+1> Push(Stack<T, n>)` and `Stack<T, n-1> Pop(Stack<T, n>)` and *know* that popping an empty stack is a violation of the non-negative-int constraint.

Comment: I disagree that this question lacks focus; it is somewhat verbose, but it asks a clear question about language design. I've voted to re-open.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks very much for your detailed answer, Eric.

Comment: @allmhuran How would the programmer see the constraints on the type say in Visual Studio? Some kind of Intellisense on the parameters when typing or hovering over the code?

Comment: @Matthew Something of that sort, yeah. Of course we could just use comments for this, but then we're back to the problem that the comments are independent of the code, and so they can get out of sync - as comments often tend to do unless you have a highly disciplined team.

Comment: @allmhuran I've solved a similar problem to this by generating c# code from XML schemas using T4 templates. I generated the c#, comments, and constraint checking code

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'll seriously consider that approach.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered to my satisfaction through a combination of the comments by Eric Lippert and Matthew.

There is no particular built in language support, nor any particular annotation package, but one possibly functional approach may be to use T4 text templates.